# Instaling latest version of Allegro with Code Blocks

Tags: windows, installation, codeblocks, allegro

In the wiki tutorial 
http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Windows_Vista,_Code%3a%3aBlocks_10.05_and_Allegro_5
I have installed MinGW correctly, but I'm not finding the allegro-5.0.x-mingw-4.a.b folder the libraries should be in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to click in "The Allegro Files" and download the MinGW files. Thanks for LennyLen from allegro.cc forums for solving that one for me.